# Considering user experience, what is the best device (phone or tablet) for AR apps?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

Where Google demonstrates ARCore usually with a smartphone, Apple does that with an iPad. Therefore my question, considering user experience as the most important thing, what is the best device (phone or tablet), to use an AR app.

*The answer(s) to this question might become opinionated very quickly, but I hope to find a good, objective answer(s) here or to start an interesting discussion on this subject.*

Answer (score 2):

The best AR demo device is no doubt the [F35 pilot's helmet](https://youtu.be/1Bg0AkinWTQ). I hope the modest price tag of $400K will not deter you.

Microsoft HoloLens and MagicLeap glasses are also nice, but not available for consumers on the date I am writing this.

For demo, you can actually use Oculus or cheaper VR sets, if you want only to show pre-recorded AR experience.

Answer (score 1):

As an opinion, based on some hands-on experience, I'd say ***currently,*** the iPhone X, running 1OS 12, and using ARKit 2 compiled with XCode 10. The main reason for this is the True Depth front facing camera; I have been able to do eye tracking with it.
Some Open Source projects that have eye tracking or otherwise use the True Depth camera (I got started from these):

- [Apple Developer: Creating Face-Based AR Experiences](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face-based_ar_experiences)
- [Apple Developer: Streaming Depth Data from the TrueDepth Camera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera)
- [GitHub: virakri/eye-tracking-ios-prototype](https://github.com/virakri/eye-tracking-ios-prototype)
- [Github: andrewzimmer906/HeatMapEyeTracking](https://github.com/andrewzimmer906/HeatMapEyeTracking)

I have a Magic Leap device, but have not yet gone beyond the hello world stage. And I can carry an iPhone X around, and use it without stares or comments, but the ML device is likely to be about as well received as Google Glass in bar.

Answer (score 0):

Considering user AR experience, the best device for Augmented Reality is the one that has well-calibrated **Accelerometer** and **Gyroscope** sensors, and high-quality RGB back camera.

All Apple phones and tablets with **A9 chipset** and higher, have well-calibrated sensors:

- iPhones – `SE` / `6s` / `7` / `8` / `X` / `Xs` / `Xr` / `11` / `11 Pro`
- iPads – `2017` /`2017 Pro` / `2018` / `2018 Pro` / `2019`

The best ones that tailored for a robust AR experience are, of course, iPhones of X-series and iPads Pro-series (they have more powerful CPU/GPU, neural engines and TrueDepth front camera).

Android flagmans, such as Google, Huawei, or Samsung, also have well-calibrated IMUs, but the majority of low-end Android phones have no gyroscope at all. So many Android users can't build a robust AR experience or have no AR experience at all.